# Google Maps Rectangle method contains with bug

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation, prototypejs

Well, I have a Google Maps instance in which I have a TraceHandler. That let the user make lines by city map. With these lines I am using google DirectionsRoute service to generate a route. The service returns various information, entre elas the *overview_path. Containing all points of directions change in my route. With these points i create triangles as follow:

```
            var triangle;
            for (var indexerTrian = 0; indexerTrian < self.bounds.length; indexerTrian++) {

                if (indexerTrian + 1 == self.bounds.length) break;

                var maxLng = self.bounds[indexerTrian].lng() < self.bounds[indexerTrian + 1].lng() ? self.bounds[indexerTrian].lng() : self.bounds[indexerTrian + 1].lng();
                var minLng = self.bounds[indexerTrian].lng() > self.bounds[indexerTrian + 1].lng() ? self.bounds[indexerTrian].lng() : self.bounds[indexerTrian + 1].lng();

                var latLngSouthWest = new gMap.LatLng(self.bounds[indexerTrian].lat(), maxLng);
                var latLngNorthEast = new gMap.LatLng(self.bounds[indexerTrian + 1].lat(), minLng);

                triangle= new gMap.LatLngBounds(latLngSouthWest, latLngNorthEast);

                self.triangles.push(triangle);
            }
```

The third part of this routine use those triangles to bring points in the route. Some code:

```
//for each point
for (var i in result.page) {
                    stopPoint = result.page[i];
                    latLng = new gMap.LatLng(stopPoint.latitude, stopPoint.longitude);

                    //for each triangle
                    for (var iTrian = 0; iTrian < self.triangles.length; iTrian++) {

                        //this guy verify if the stopPoint is inside the triangle.
                        //if so. Drop it on map
                        if (self.triangles[iTrian].contains(latLng)) {

                            //this method just generate a Marker instance.
                            self.SetaMarkers(latLng, iconMarker, stopPoint.descricao, true);
                            counter++;
                            break;
                        }
                        //this is a DEBUG if who prints all points if my loop comes to 
                        //end
                        else if ((iTrian + 1) == self.triangles.length) {

                            self.SetaMarkers(latLng, null, stopPoint.descricao, true);
                            //break;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

This works good. No erros at execution. But for those triangles who I change de Longitude their *.contains* don't work. It may be a bug.

Here is an image to demonstrate. I'm printing the triangles to debug: http://s7.postimage.org/ek3prgryj/Map.png As u guys can see in the image. The *normal* red marker is those **stopPoint** that is out of the bounds of all triangles. And those with a edited image is the **stopPoints** in the bounds of some triangle.

I have tried a lot of things already.. now im going to print the center of each triangle to see if it is where it must be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem using a circle of 25 meters after 25 meters of the route. Now I can let the user set the *radius* and it's getting everyone.